# using gnuplot dumb terminal ASCII graph in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

gnuplot ASCII graph is amazing.
I'd like to include gnuplot dumb ASCII graph results in babel code block.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC gnuplot :results output :file gnuplot-dumb-plot.txt
set term dumb
set yrange [0:1.5]
plot [-2:2] exp(-x*x)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
```

Alas, first line of gnuplot-dumb-plot.txt includes `^L` line feed control code.

Therefore, `#+RESULTS:` does not work.

Adding another `#+INCLUDE:` with example block specified does work.

```
#+INCLUDE: gnuplot-dumb-plot.txt example
```

or excluding first line with `:lines` specified,

```
#+INCLUDE: gnuplot-dumb-plot.txt example :lines "2-"
```

or by sed deleting first line

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh
sed -e '1d' gnuplot-dumb-plot.txt
#+END_SRC
```

work, but are not elegant.

```
#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
      +--------+-------+--------+--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+
  1.4 +-+      +       +        +        +       +        +       +      +-+
      |                                                  exp(-x*x) ******* |
      |                                                                    |
  1.2 +-+                                                                +-+
      |                                                                    |
    1 +-+                              ****                              +-+
      |                            ****    ****                            |
      |                          ***          ***                          |
  0.8 +-+                       *                *                       +-+
      |                       **                  **                       |
  0.6 +-+                   **                      **                   +-+
      |                    **                        **                    |
      |                  **                            **                  |
  0.4 +-+              **                                **              +-+
      |              ***                                  ***              |
  0.2 +-+          ***                                      ***          +-+
      |         ***                                            ***         |
      +   ******       +        +        +       +        +       ******   +
    0 ****-----+-------+--------+--------+-------+--------+-------+-----****
     -2      -1.5     -1      -0.5       0      0.5       1      1.5       2

#+end_example
```

Are there any options or hacks for including gnuplot dumb ASCII graphs?

### Thanks to @wvxvw, it turned out to be:

- Note: Emacs 24.5.1, org-mode 8.3.2, gnuplot Version 5.0 patchlevel 1, Mac OS X 10.10.5.
- `:session none` is required in gnuplot code block for printing ASCII graph in `#+RESULTS:` .

  - I wish if gnuplot has an option such as `noheadfeed` for deleting a top `^L` / or, perhaps org-babel might manage in the future.
- **HTML export**

  - `:results output verbatim` in gnuplot code block enables printing ASCII graph at `#+RESULTS:` within org-mode.
  - `org-html-export-as-html` works. This seems to be a simple solution if you don't need LaTeX.
  - But `^L` appears in the beginning of `#+RESULTS:` which later makes error at LaTeX.
- **LaTeX export**

  - Due to `^L`, "Forbidden control sequence" in LaTeX, `org-latex-export-to-pdf` fails.
  - For LaTeX export, do not `C-c C-c` at gnuplot code block. `#+RESULTS:` at gnuplot should be left blank.
  - `:exports none` is also required in gnuplot code block for avoiding LaTeX error.
- **Org-mode, HTML, LaTeX**

  - @wvxvw's solution removing `^L` (`\014`) succeeds in org-mode `#+RESULTS`, HTML/LaTeX exports.
  - Use `#+NAME:` , `:var` , `#+CALL:` for output a clean ASCII graph `#+RESULTS:` (without `^L`)

Comment: Instead of outputting to a file you could add another source block with, say, Emacs Lisp code where you'd assign the output of the GNUPlot to a variable, i.e. `:var=graph()` (assuming you previously named the GNUPlot block with `#+name: graph`) and then remove the extra line in the output.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your advice! Unfortunately, perhaps due to "^L" control code, #+RESULTS: yields nothing on the org-mode, therefore variable labelled with #+NAME: graph seems to be nil...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the example code for what I meant. Also note that you need `:session none` since otherwise the output isn't generated. This looks like a bug to me in `org-babel-execute:gnuplot`, so, if you feel like it, you could write to Org mailing list about it. ;)

```
#+NAME: pp_ascii_gnuplot
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var plot=""
  (mapconcat 'identity (cl-subseq (split-string plot "\n") 2 -2) "\n")
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: graph
#+BEGIN_SRC gnuplot :results output :session none
set term dumb
set yrange [0:1.5]
plot [-2:2] exp(-x*x)
#+END_SRC

#+CALL: pp_ascii_gnuplot(plot=graph())

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
      +--------+-------+--------+--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+
  1.4 ++       +       +        +        +       +        exp(-x*x) ******++
      |                                                                    |
      |                                                                    |
  1.2 ++                                                                  ++
      |                                                                    |
    1 ++                               ****                               ++
      |                            ****    ****                            |
      |                          ***          ***                          |
  0.8 ++                        *                *                        ++
      |                       **                  **                       |
  0.6 ++                    **                      **                    ++
      |                    **                        **                    |
      |                  **                            **                  |
  0.4 ++               **                                **               ++
      |              ***                                  ***              |
  0.2 ++           ***                                      ***           ++
      |         ***                                            ***         |
      +   ******       +        +        +       +        +       ******   +
    0 ****-----+-------+--------+--------+-------+--------+-------+-----****
     -2      -1.5     -1      -0.5       0      0.5       1      1.5       2
#+end_example
```

Comment: I really thank you for your kind and detailed advice.
A Combination of gnuplot :session none, split-string in Emacs Lisp, #+CALL: in org-mode knocked me down !
But I can't replicate the results yet )-: , on Emacs 24.5.1, org-mode 8.3.2, Mac OS X 10.10.5.
evaluating #+CALL: still yields blank. I'll struggle to catch up your advice.

Comment: @RUserPassingBy I have a newer version of Emacs and am doing this on Linux. One way I'd try to test it is by just outputting a string with `^L` in it from one source block and seeing if it gets into another source block unaffected. If you need to insert `^L` in a string, something like "foo\014bar" should work.

Comment: Oh, I thank @wvxvw ! It works ! In my environment, I need `:results output verbatim` in gnuplot block, `:results output value` in Emacs Lisp and `#+CALL:` blocks. Now, I'm ready to dive into deep ASCII world ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @wvxvw's many advice, I attempted a short try. I'll never figure it out without @wvxvw's advice on `:session none` and code `\014`.

```
#+NAME: graph
#+BEGIN_SRC gnuplot :results output verbatim :session none :exports none
set term dumb
set yrange [0:1.5]
plot [-2:2] exp(-x*x)
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results output value :exports both :var tmp=graph :exports both
(cadr (split-string tmp "\014"))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
```